# Software to send SMS's via bluetooth

Tags: windows, android

I have been using [MightyText](http://mightytext.net/) for a long time but as I am becoming more and more aware about privacy issues with software that you aren't 100% certain that you know what they are doing with your data. I am also becoming more and more mobile nowadays so I don't always have internet (which is what mightytext requires) but would still like to use my laptop to send SMS's.

I am looking for a piece of software for Windows (7 or 8) that allows me to connect my Android phone (Android 2.2 and up) to my laptop via bluetooth to send and receive SMS messages. This software should **not** require any internet connection at all and should **never** "call home" to send my personal information to its servers.

Required features:

- Must connect to Android 2.2 and up (including 4.4)
- Must work with both Windows 7 and 8
- Must connect via Bluetooth (other connections such as WiFi and USB are optional)
- Must never call home or need internet
- Must be able to send and receive SMS messages. MMS messages are optional. Calling notifications from the software is also optional
- Price is not of importance, but the closer to zero the better. Ads are not of importance
- In the software, I should be able to see and reply to to SMS messages that I have received with the name, date and message displayed. Group messages should also be displayed
- Would be very nifty if it integrated with Windows 8's notification system, but not a requirement

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying [SMS Control Center](http://www.smscontrolcenter.com/) [(Play store link)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smscontrolcenter&hl=en) and I have been very impressed with it so far.

> SMS Control Center allows you to create, send and receive SMS from PC via mobile phone connected to your computer.

It has a Microsoft Office 2007 look to it and has the option of either displaying conversations by grouping contacts messages together (like what you would usually see on your phone) or by having an inbox where all messages by all contacts get thrown together. Overall its a pretty good looking piece of free software that doesn't disappoint on features.

Features:

- Can sync to Android 2.2 and up
- Can sync via Bluetooth, WiFi or a USB cable
- Can send and receive SMS messages as well as place phone calls
- Syncs contacts from phone and you can import contacts from Outlook
- I ran a network listener for an hour or so while using this, and it never once connected to the internet. Not even on shutdown or startup. Besides, you can just use an application blocker to block internet access for that app
- Totally free with no ads, but does accept donations
- Although it doesn't have Windows 8 notification support it displays a notification in the top right corner with an option to reply, delete or call. It plays a sound of your choice upon receiving it
- Has rules for incoming SMS messages to do different things like play different sounds for different contacts or send an email when an SMS is received from a specific contact
- Search and print functions
- Can export SMS's to a XML file

Comment: SMS Control Center Still works great although it appears unsupported by the developer.  No longer accepts donations but offers a free license code to unlock all features. There are a couple minor UI "things" that I would've liked to see function differently but for the price (free) and how long I've been looking for an app like this (longtime) it's a great application!  (Technically 2 applications working together, one Android app from Play Store, one from the developer's site.)